# WebView inside SherlockFragment - FragmentTransaction.Detach() does not remove the webview

Tags: android, webview, actionbarsherlock, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I am using ActionBarSherlock's action bar tabs in my application with each tab populated by a single fragment inside a SherlockActivity `Tabs`.

One of my Tabs contains a fragment, `FragmentHome`, with a list of news articles. When an article is selected, `FragmentHome` is replaced by another fragment, `FragmentNews`.

FragmentNews just contains a webview to load the selected article. The article is loaded fine.  I override the `onBackPressed` in my activity so that `FragmentHome` is reattached and `FragmentNews` is removed.

While there are no errors, the webview inside `FragmentHome` is never removed from the view and overlaps with other fragments. (See screenshots)

[image: FragmentHome - OK]
[image: FragmentNews - OK] 
[image: FragmentHome w/webview interference]

Its weird because the same code works for a another `SherlockFragment` with `ListView` in it but is messed up when using a `WebView`. Here is the code to replace `FragmentHome` with `FragmentNews` initially:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    listNews.setItemChecked(position, true);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("NEWS",
            new String[] {
                    mNews.newsFeed.get(position).getTitle(),
                    mNews.newsFeed.get(position).getLink()
                            .toExternalForm() });

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment frag = SherlockFragment.instantiate(getSherlockActivity(),
            FragmentNews.class.getName(), bundle);
    ft.detach(getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(getId()));
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag, Tabs.FRAG_NEWS);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Overriden onBackPressed in Tabs:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            FRAG_DETAILS);

    if (frag != null && frag.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(frag);

        Fragment mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                TAB_PORTFOLIO);
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(this,
                    FragmentPortfolioList.class.getName(), null);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, TAB_PORTFOLIO);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);

        }
        ft.commit();
    } else {

        frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_NEWS);
        if (frag != null && !frag.isDetached()) {
            Log.e("onBackPressed", "for " + frag.getTag());
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(frag);

            Fragment mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAB_HOME);
            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(this,
                        FragmentHome.class.getName(), null);
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, TAB_HOME);
            } else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            Log.e("onBackPressed", "inside else");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet from FragmentNews

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arr = getArguments().getStringArray("NEWS");
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container);
        newsView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_WV_Brief);
        newsView.getSettings()
                .setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        newsView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
        newsView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);

        newsView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e("override", url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        newsView.loadUrl(arr[1]);

    }
```

I have seen posts talking about FlashPlayer causing issues because of SurfaceView cutting a hole but I am just displaying simple webpages without any videos. Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem while going over the source code of WebViewFragment. I realized there isn't much going on other than pause/resume of webview.

I had two serious errors in my code:

1. I never returned the inflated view in `onCreatView` in
   `FragmentNews`. I was returning `super.onCreateView(inflater,
   container, savedInstanceState).`
2. I forgot to set `attachToRoot` to `false` in `onCreateView` when
   inflating the XML layout - `View view =
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, **false**)`

Therefore, the inflated view was just standing on its own without being attached to the fragment. When the fragment was replaced, it resulted in a mashed up display because the inflated layout containing the `WebView` was never removed. Unfortunately, this complied without errors.